# Why does Firebase Phone Auth take a long time to send an SMS Verification Code on some carriers?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

There are some carriers in the Philippines that tale a long time to receive a verification code. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this has anything to do with Firebase SDK. The problem maybe the service providers you're using.